# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mustache

Пытаюсь по гайду сделать простенькое веб-приложение.
В проекте использую Spring Boot, и на моменте компиляции ловлю непонятное исключение.
Код всех файлов вставляю ниже:

```
package com.example.ProjectTasks;

import com.example.ProjectTasks.domain.Message;
import com.example.ProjectTasks.repos.MessageRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World")
                                       String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "Greeting";
    }
    @GetMapping
    public String main(Map<String, Object> model){
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        model.put("some", messages);
        return "main";

    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model){
         Message message = new Message(text, tag);
         messageRepo.save(message);
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        model.put("some", messages);
        return "main";

    }
}
```

Репозиторий

```
package com.example.ProjectTasks.repos;

import com.example.ProjectTasks.domain.Message;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MessageRepo extends CrudRepository<Message, Integer> {
}
```

Непосредственно сайт

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введите текст">
        <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="Введите тег">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
        <div>Список сообщений</div>
        {{#messages}}
            <div>
                <b>{{id}}</b>
                <span>{{text}}</span>
                <i>{{tag}}</i>
            </div>
        {{/messages}}
    </body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Класс Message

```
package com.example.ProjectTasks.domain;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, String tag){
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Файл со всеми зависимостями

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectTasks</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Файл с которого начинается компиляция

```
package com.example.ProjectTasks;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

При компиляции ловлю вот такой лог.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63021', transport: 'socket'
23:57:16.707 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
23:57:16.725 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/]
23:57:16.726 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/Education/com.example/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2021-12-05 23:57:18.166  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ProjectTasks.Application     : Starting Application on DESKTOP-I07G2IT with PID 4708 (D:\Education\com.example\target\classes started by Леся in D:\Education\com.example)
2021-12-05 23:57:18.168  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.ProjectTasks.Application     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-05 23:57:18.334  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@11deb3e: startup date [Sun Dec 05 23:57:18 EET 2021]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/%d0%9b%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-12-05 23:57:21.964  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d1c5db4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-12-05 23:57:22.704  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-05 23:57:22.747  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-05 23:57:22.747  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2021-12-05 23:57:22.757  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [D:\Education\jdk\jdk11\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;D:\Education\jdk\jdk11\bin;D:\Education\new jdk\bin;D:\Education\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;D:\Education\git\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Леся\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Леся\.dotnet\tools;.]
2021-12-05 23:57:22.933  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-05 23:57:22.933  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4599 ms
2021-12-05 23:57:23.212  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2021-12-05 23:57:23.220  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2021-12-05 23:57:23.220  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2021-12-05 23:57:23.220  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2021-12-05 23:57:23.221  INFO 4708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2021-12-05 23:57:23.506  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-12-05 23:57:23.715  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-12-05 23:57:23.956  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-12-05 23:57:23.983  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2021-12-05 23:57:24.265  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final}
2021-12-05 23:57:24.271  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2021-12-05 23:57:24.408  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2021-12-05 23:57:24.759  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2021-12-05 23:57:25.162  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ProjectTasks.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Метод org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() ещё не реализован
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

2021-12-05 23:57:25.167  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@ba8f85
2021-12-05 23:57:25.975  WARN 4708 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2021-12-05 23:57:25.977  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-12-05 23:57:26.002  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-12-05 23:57:26.005  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-05 23:57:26.051  INFO 4708 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-05 23:57:26.081 ERROR 4708 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ProjectTasks.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(Ent
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63021', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стектрейсе указана реальная проблема чуть ниже:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Метод org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() ещё не реализован
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.1.jar:42.2.1]
```

Это известная проблема Hibernate, для решения которой в указанной версии Spring Boot 2.0.0 рекомендуется установить флаг в `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Данная проблема была решена в Hibernate 5.4.0.CR1, поэтому можно либо обновить Hibernate, добавив версию зависимости в pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Либо поднять версию Spring Boot до 2.2.x и выше -- там уже используется обновленный Hibernate.

Comment: Помогло, но лишь отчасти, но кол-во ошибок в логе стало меньше, но одна так и не убралась. org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Answer (score 0):

Итого, помогло решение сверху + добавил в application.properties такие строчки

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Последнюю строчку рекомендую установить значение update

Comment: А если намного проще, то действительно, лучше просто выбрать версию спринга повыше.